# Graphic problems with libgdx stage2d.ui

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm playing with stage2d.ui...
Just creating an empty stage with only a button, and it happens this in android (screenshot directly from a Nexus5):
[image: Screenshot from a Nexus5]

Also, it looks ok in desktop, but if you resize the screen, you can see the image of the button flickering at its previous position like this (image after making the window a bit more width):
[image: Desktop behaviour]

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it's just a graphic issue...

For the button widget, I'm using the test data like this:

```
stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));

TextButton button = new TextButton("Button 1", skin);
button.setSize(100, 50);
button.setPosition(10, 10);

stage.addActor(button);
```

And then in the main render method, `stage.act(delta)` and `stage.draw()` are called, of course.

For the resize part... here's the code

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

I have other stages without ui widgets working fine, but this is my first time with ui and I'm not sure about what's happening here...

Comment: I use [tables](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.html) not coordinates.

Comment: My guess is you are not clearing the screen at the start of your render method. Try adding Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); if it isn't there already.

Comment: @Fish it was just a test. Not worth to create a table...

Comment: @nEx.Software oh man! how come I forgot that? Thanks, that was it lol.
If you make it a reply, I'd accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved from comment above.

My guess is you are not clearing the screen at the start of your render method. Try adding `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` if it isn't there already.

Comment: I’m ashamed of forgetting this, but maybe it can be useful for other people :)